# CSS not working on dynamically created content [jQuery]

Tags: jquery, css

My code seems to be working on content that comes from the HTML file, but not dynamically created elements.

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
}
```

It also doesn't work with `css()`. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?  What is/is not happening that expect to/to not happen?

Comment: A jquery event will never bind to an element that is created after the binding function is called. Basically, your jquery is unaware of the new elements you created. You'll need to bind the event to them after they are created and inserted into the DOM. You'll need to add the code that creates the elements for a more complete answer.

Comment: Add or reset the listener after you add in the dynamically created content.

Comment: Use this `$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){...})` if the `ul` exists already.  If not then find a parent of where the `ul` will be and bind to that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
} );
```

The event listener is attached to the document. But triggers the callback only when a `<li>` element is clicked.

---

Your original code doesn't work because the event listener is attached to existing elements. But it is not automatically attached to new elements created later.

---

As [Erik Philips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209259/erik-philips) correctly commented, this is not very performant if you have a page with lots of elements.

You may substitute `document` with a "parent" element that contains your `<li>` elements.

This may be simply the cointainer `<ul>` node. If you have many give it an *id* and use that for reference: `$( '#the_list' ).on( 'click', 'li', function()...`

This will avoid jQuery to parse the whole document in search of `<li>` nodes at each click.

Comment: This is not the preferred way to bind to dynamic elements as you're actually binding to every event in the document and then filtering which *could* have performance issues.  Typically one should replace `document` with a static container where dynamic elements are added.

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes, of course. I improved my answer to point that out.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a closing ) at the end of that function. I just dropped your code into a jsfiddle and it worked fine.